# jQuery Disable a button and change its style for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on an audio player and I'd like to disable the "NEXT" button for 3 seconds, and make it slightly transparent during that same amount of time.

The disable function seems to work, but when I'm adding the change of style to it then nothing works anymore.

Here is what I got so far :

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-fw" id="fwd"></i>
```

jQuery

```
var clickLock = 0;

$('#fwd').on('click', function(){
    if (clickLock == 0) {
        clickLock = 1;

        setTimeout(function(){  
           clickLock = 0;
        }, 3000);
    }

});

$(function(){
 $('#fwd').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#fwd').removeClass('disabled');}, 3000);
});
```

css

```
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: why do you have two `on click` listeners?

Comment: *"nothing works anymore"*: what do you mean? All the code you posted seems to work, so something must be missing in your question.

Comment: I had another jQuery command (to show a modal popup) that did not work anymore, but I don't think that was related. What I meant is that adding the "disabled" class to it made every other commands not working, including the disabling one.

Comment: Actually, the reason for that was answered better by Michael Coker.. see his answer, you forgot `});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do it like that:

```
var clickLock = 0;

$('#fwd').on('click', function(){
    if (clickLock == 0) {
        clickLock = 1;
        $('#fwd').addClass('disabled');

        setTimeout(function(){  
           clickLock = 0;
           $('#fwd').removeClass('disabled');
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Although that is a good idea, how does this explain the problem the OP has?

Comment: @trincot OP stated that this piece of code is working. And second piece of code doesn't do anything extra, only complicate things. Why don't use `addClass`/`removeClass` in place where it is working...

Comment: @laser, see the other answer of Michael Coker

Comment: @trincot please, see my comment under OP post first.

Answer (score 2):

What you have works, you're just missing `});` at the end of your function that wraps the `$.click()` handler on `#fwd`.

If you're working on something and you have a syntax error like this, check your browser console and you should see an error that can point you to the problem.

```js
var clickLock = 0;

$('#fwd').on('click', function() {
  if (clickLock == 0) {
    clickLock = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickLock = 0;
    }, 3000);
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('#fwd').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fwd').removeClass('disabled');
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-fw" id="fwd">click</i>
```

Comment: This answer actually explains what was the problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

You're problem might be that you are binding the disabling click handle before the diviner has loaded. Try moving it to the jQuery `ready`.

You could drastically simplify your code by using a semantic button element and styling it accordingly.

```
function disableButton(event) {
  var $button = $(event.target);
  $button.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

  setTimeout(function(){  
    $button.removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled', false);
  }, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#forward-button').on('click', disableButton);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/pubemawomu/edit?output